# Magento Performance slow even with one user only on EC2 instance and RDS

Tags: performance, magento, caching, amazon-ec2, rds

I currently have a magento website, on a dedicated server.
Not really happy with TTFB (around 2.5s with the home page).
I have only 3000 visitors per day, 15 000 pages /day.
I have 30 000 products, 1 store, 1 language, 1 currency.

I thought I could make a try with EC2/RDS from amazon, so I copied my website on a new EC2 instance (web server) + 1 RDS for mysql for testing purpose.
I started with a small one (t2.small), same for RDS.
I setup nginx+php5-fpm, and imported my magento (files + DB)

I was very surprised, around 5s for TTFB!! 
For 1 user (myself!). accessing only  the home page, I never went somewhere else.
I have the same poor TTFB when I access a CMS page that only displays the newsletter form (+ header and footer), no products at all displayed.

I migrated to a better RDS (db.r3.large, 2CPU,15GB,110GB SSD), it was 5s.
Still a lot.

I upgraded the EC2 instance too (c3.2xlarge, 8CPU 15GB)
Now it is 3.5s, still more than my current dedicated server, with 1 user only.

I know there are options like making magento code better, but my point is more about why EC2 instance with only 1 user connected is performing less than my current prod server (which is 8CPU 8GB only, so half the size, and it has everything, even the DB while my EC2 config has 2 servers!)

My nginx vhosts have been configured the same than my prod server (but nginx.conf might differ).

Same with redis.
 BTW on EC2 I noticed 0 difference with or without Redis (same TTFB), I assume Redis makes a difference when there are a lot of users, and a lot of files cached. (I'm sure Redis is working, because I can see KEYS added, and var/cache folder remains empty once enabled)
 I haven't tryed to optimize mysql config, I'm assuming AWS/RDS has by default something good enough.

Out of monitoring I can read (last 1 hour):

- RDS: 
  ReadIOPS peak: 1.5  - WriteIOPS peak at 1.15 - CPU: max is
  0.80%
- EC2 : CPU max: 1.5 %

everything is sleeping or I'm wondering if I miss something important, maybe I can't expect a better TTFB just because EC2 are shared (and not reserved)? AWS adds some latency somewhere because of that?

**EDIT 1:**

I just upgraded RDS to db.r3.2xlarge (8CPUs, 64GB), now it's 3.1s to display a home page (2.8s for the newsletter CMS page). Still more than my server...

**EDIT 2:**

I just upgraded RDS SSD to provisionned IOPS instead of general purpose. now it's 3.0s. So no enhancement...

Can you confirm the size of the servers are really huge for my website (1 user accessing the home page only!!) ?

**EDIT 3:**

Now I have 0.8s :-) Thanks to amazing AOE_Profile I found the bottleneck being Cmsmart_Megamenu. I have more than 100 categories and it does something strange. 127 queries per category!! so more than 10 000 queries (with every page)! The 127 queries /cat are almost identical, like this one is repeated 127 times:

> SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `admin_menutop` AS `main_table` WHERE (category_id = '356')

Actually, it does NOT change anything to this topic, it is even more important now to get help. I was not looking for fixing the issue (that could be another topic). I still wonder why the EC2 performs less, actually I will keep this module in place on the EC2 server until I understand why it performs worse than my less-powerfull current prod server (both having this DB-CPU-consumming module).

Can it be because on my prod server I always have several visitors connected , so the mysql caching performs better? while on EC2 the cache is removed when all active connections are closed so it has to hit the DB?

this is the type of hints I'm looking for :-)

Thansk

Comment: Do you have php optimizer installed? You may also want to install new relic to identify where your issues are.

Comment: Not the question you asked (so it's in a comment), but Magento has a pretty unique performance profile.  For a site like you're describing you're better off going with one of the Magento VPS hosting specialists (Nexcess, MageMojo, etc).  While they're handling you site hosting for you can examine exactly how they've deployed Magento and learn what's wrong with your Amazon configuration at your leisure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @datasage: yes I have Zend opcache (+Redis+memcache). All enabled. I guess it does not help when you have a website without activity.

Comment: @Alan: that's my current situation. My prod server is on such environment from a magento specialist. Still I would like to manage myself now and go on AWS so I have more flexibiliy. I have setup the same config (by reading all files from my prod server), that's why I'm wondering why performance are worst. I don't want to conclude EC2 has poor performance, so I guess I miss something

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue wih admin_menutop table (I'm using Cmsmart_Megamenu too), NewRelic told me about that hundreds of queries per categories too.

You said it was the bottleneck, but didn't mention what was the fix :). Can you please share that with me?